# Sustainable way to share grails domain classes?

Tags: git, grails

We're currently using the grails plugin capabilities for sharing a domain model across related components. Here's a sanitized example of what we're looking at

- product-domain-plugin-[version].zip
- product-admin-[version].war
- product-manager-[version].war
- product-mobile-services-[version].war

On the developer workstation we have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
code/
├── product-domain-plugin/
├── product-admin/
├── product-manager/
├── product-mobile-services/
```

Each project is its own git repository, using a `git-flow` convention. During development of `product-admin` for example, we'll have the `product-domain-plugin` inlined in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.plugin.location.productdomainplugin = "../product-domain-plugin"
```

For product releases, we package the `product-domain-plugin` as a plugin, deploy it to our internal artifactory server, and call it `product-domain-plugin-4.0.zip`.

In the release branch of each `product-*` grails apps, we modify the `BuildConfig.groovy` file to grab the packaged version of the plugin (this is so we can guarantee that the build environment is versioned along with the shared domain code):

```
compile ':product-domain-plugin:4.0'
```

When the application is released through jira, the build server checks out the master branch which references the external plugin and builds the artifact (which looks like `product-admin-4.0.war`).

Why do we do this?

- We keep the grails projects separated, so we can update one without necessarily affecting the others (e.g., hotfix the mobile services without re-tagging the admin app)
- By using a packaged plugin instead of an inlined one, every part of the build is still versioned
- The developer can choose to only checkout the components he needs, such as `product-mobile-services`, and rely on the latest release of the domain plugin
- We've established a version number convention that signifies that a grails application with version x.y.z was built with packaged domain plugin version x.y, and has a hotfix z

However, often we find ourselves developing the feature in the plugin and the grails application simultaneously (hence the inline config). Essentially the only way we can tell if the plugin works (or is exactly what we need it to be) is to test it under a web application. The final war file that's deployed has no inlined domain plugin. So in order:

1. Build/deploy the domain plugin to our artifactory server at a specific version
2. Modify all the grails apps to use the packaged version of the plugin from our artifactory server
3. Go through normal QA testing of the grails apps and release them

The problem is if/when an issue with the domain plugin is discovered in step 1. There's no way to QA test the plugin, since it only interacts with other grails apps. When a problem is detected and solved we update the version number of the domain plugin (since grails considers the previous one already released and rightly caches the artifact from the server) and re-deploy to our server. This could get tedious during QA testing, and seems like it could be improved.

I've thought of using git submodules for this, but it seems like the domain plugin submodule would need to be a part of each grails application. It seems like it would be pretty messy to keep 3 different clones of the same domain plugin repository up to date for 3 grails projects.

Sorry for the wall of text. Hopefully I've made everything clear enough. Surely there's an easier way to manage this? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the maven local repository as an intermediate, private publication point for local Q/A testing prior to publication to your Artifactory repository. Our normal workflow for joint application/plugin development is something like this:

1. Develop functionality in application/plugin using inline plugin configuration in application BuildConfig.groovy and run-test, run-app.
2. Test plugin resolution and packaging using a SNAPSHOT release version of the plugin. Append "-SNAPSHOT" to the version of the plugin you are developing and publish it to the local maven repository using "maven-install". Update the plugin configuration in your app to remove the inline dependency, replacing it with a "compile" statement and the SNAPSHOT version of the plugin. Refresh-dependencies will pick up the plugin from the local repository and compile the whole app. Test the application using run-test and run-war to ensure that packaging and deployment will work properly.
3. Publish the release version of the plugin to artifactory after removing the -SNAPSHOT from the version number. Update the application BuildConfig.groovy to refer to the published plugin and re-execute your run-test and run-war commands.

This should significantly reduced you exposure to plugin packaging issues. The maven-intall and SNAPSHOT support is part of Grails proper.